# Why does ListDataModel not work with a bounded type parameter?

Tags: java, generics, jsf-2

I just tried to create a [`ListDataModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/ListDataModel.html) with a bounded type, like this:

```
DataModel<? extends Foo> model = new ListDataModel<? extends Foo>(fooList);
```

, where `fooList` is of the type `List<? extends Foo>`. I get the following error:

```
unexpected type
  required: class or interface without bounds
  found: ? extends Foo
```

My current workaround is to copy my data into an `ArrayList<Foo>`, and build a `DataModel<Foo>` from that, but I would like to know why this is necessary, and if there is any way to make it work?

Comment: Noted should be that this issue is not specific to JSF, if you were wondering that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<? extends Foo>` means "some type, I don't know which one, which is or extends Foo". When constructing the data model, you need to tell him which type of data it contains, not just one unknown type.

Just construct your data model like this:

```
DataModel<? extends Foo> model = new ListDataModel<Foo>(fooList);
```

Unfortunately, the `ListDataModel<Foo>` constructor only accepts a `List<Foo>`, and not a `List<? extends Foo>`. It seems to me like a misconception. For example the `HashSet<E>` constructor takes a `Collection<? extends E>` as argument. If you accept the type safety warning, just casting your list to a `List<Foo>` should work.

Comment: The problem is that `fooList` is of type `List<? extends Foo>`, and this is not a valid argument-type for the constructor of `ListDataModel<Foo>`. I am just wondering why `ListDataModel` needs to know the actual type.

Comment: Oops. You're right. It also seems to me like a misconception. For example the HashSet<E> constructor takes a Collection<? extends E> as argument. If you accept the type safety warning, just casting your list to a List<Foo> should work.

Comment: This did the trick, thank you. If you update your answer to include this comment, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Since `ListDataModel` is read only, it is wrong for its constructor to accept only `List<E>`. It's ok to cast to bypass this design flaw.

A more general question: suppose `ListDataModel` is writable, what now?

If `fooList` is a `List<? extends Foo>`, then it certainly is a `List<W>` for a concrete `W` which extends `Foo`. Then we should be able to `new ListDataModel<W>(fooList)`, the result type is a `DataModel<W>`, which is assignable to `DataModel<? extends Foo> model`.

This is how compiler internally reason about wildcards (wildcard capture); too bad we can't access `W` directly in Java (it's a so called non-denotable type), but we can cause wildcard capture through method invocation:

```
static <W> ListDataModel<W> make(List<W> list)
{
    return new ListDataModel<W>(list);
}

List<? extends Foo> fooList = ...;
DataModel<? extends Foo> model = make( fooList );
```

When compiling `make( fooList )`, compiler internally refines the type of `fooList` to a `List<W>` where `<W extends Foo>`; then the rest works natually.

In Java 7, type inference is extended to constructors with `<>` syntax

```
List<? extends Foo> fooList = ...;
DataModel<? extends Foo> model = new ListDataModel<>(fooList); // OK in Java 7
```

With `<>`, constructor call is pretty much the same as method calls; so `make()` is no longer needed. Prior to Java 7, static factory methods like `make()` were needed to amend the problem that constructors don't do inference. That practice is now obsolete.

Comment: Maybe the reason the `ListDataModel` constructor only accepts the `List<E>` is b/c there would be less impact if in the future the designers opted to make `ListDataModel` writable. Simply add an `addXXX()` method.

If they'd opted instead for `ListDataModel(List<? extends E>)` then if it was decided to make the class writable, they'd have to either replace that bounded generic `List` constructor with the unbounded `ListDataModel(List<E>)` _OR_  add a second `ListDataModel(List<? super E>)`.

I don't know about you, but I know which design, _**I**_ would prefer to maintain.

Comment: irreputable said: "_If fooList is a List<? extends Foo>, then it certainly **is a** List<W> for a concrete W which extends Foo_"
  
`List<? extends Foo>` **_is certainly NOT a subtype of_** `List<W>`. So  it's wrong to say  "List<? extends Foo> **_is a_** List<W>". Try instantiating a `List<? extends Foo>`; then try assigning that `List<? extends Foo>` object to a variable of type `List<W>`. And you'll see my point.